# How prevent duplicate UniqID in two different SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, database-design

I'm developing a social network website for my university. It uses a SQL Server database and every user will have a `UniqID` (it's an `Int` that increase by identity increment, started from 1 to ...).

My question is if I want to run this website in another university and on their own servers the `UniqIDs` will be start from 1 to ... , so it will cause duplicate `UniqIDs`, and its impossible to connect these two university website and students can not have connection with another university students.

I have no idea how to solve this problem? Should I use distributed database?

Please give me an idea to start.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand this, but as your using a different DB in a different location, the data itself will be different, sure the schema layout is identical but data is different, different users etc.  The IDs should only be relating to each user in that DB, on another DB it could be totally different But thats not the case as that user doesnt exist in DB1, only DB2.
If infact the data is the same then yes you need to either mimick the data etc Or just use there DB.  Please correct me as im unsure on what your question is asking

Comment: Is that possible to change datatype of UniqueID column to varchar? If so you can append College initial Letters(Say for Berkley Univ:take "Berk") along with ID(integer number).So Students ID will have value like (Berk123,Berk124) So it will be unique even if you combine.

Comment: @StevenSmith yes data are different , i want have on website that uses multiple database , each database is related to a university !  so having user1 in db 1 with uniqID of 1000 and having user1 in db 2 with uniqID of 1000 will cause problem !

Comment: @knkarthick24 yes its a good idea i will check that , thanks :)

Comment: Give each university (site) a `SiteID` and make the combination of `(SiteID, UniqID)` the primary identifying key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as there different DBs with Different Data, Cant you simply check Which DB your getting data from?
If you need to do it all DB side then dont rely on Just the ID of each user, Have something like location Like "ID 42, LocationCode UHJ"  that way it doesn't matter if the IDs are the same for "BOB" and "JOE" as you know which location there from and can tell there not the same

Comment: possibly, although you could prob check all code side without the need for a DB change.  Like suggested you could use GUID, however personally I dont like that idea as it doesnt feel "clean" to me.

Answer (score 0):

you can use UNIQUE-IDENTIFIER(GUID)  as an ID. It is guarenteed to be unique(they say so)

[unique identifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx)

Comment: That's a GUID, not an int. There are numerous performance issues with using GUIDs as keys plus they look really ugly as social network IDs

Comment: As per the link you shared, Unique Identifier values for StudentID populated using NEWID() function. There is a possibility to get the same NEWID() value occurence at any instance. So using NEWID() is not the best way to generate Unique value for any column.

Answer (score -2):

Don't let the DB assign IDs, instead generate your own IDs, perhaps using a prefix that is unique for a location e.g. students at one university are UNI1_1, UNI1_2, etc. whereas users at another university are UNI2_1, UNI2_2.